# Roslyn: How to call compiler-generated class method without reflection

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

I'm using Roslyn Project which contains

- A) A document with SourceCodeKind = Script, and
- B) Another document
  with SourceCodeKind = Regular

Lets say the script document A) contains only

```
public string myScriptFunction()
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Upon compilation, Roslyn will transform the script code into a class "MyScriptClass" that contains the method above and some initialization methods - specifically, one with the name "<Initialize>" (see code at the very bottom for specifics).

Right, and the regular document B) is something like

```
class MyRegularClass
{
    async void go()
    {
        var script = new MyScriptClass();  // This works
        await script.<Initialize>(); // whoops.. can't do! won't compile due to the invalid method name. Can do via reflection, but that seems bad.
    }
}
```

When compiling the project, the comments above already give away what happens: I can instantiate MyScriptClass just fine, so whatever Roslyn does to transform the syntax of my script file into actual C# seems to have already happened. 
But I can't access its <Initialize> method, because obviously it contains invalid characters (<, >) and Roslyn still seems to do this sanity check at that point.

My question is basically: Can I in any way generate code for document B) that can directly call the <Initialize> method?
Any setting for my project/document that will disable this check, any compiler directive, or any way of generating the code itself to circumvent this?

Currently, I'm retreating to using reflection for this call, which works fine - but if there's any way at all, I would prefer a direct call to the method of course.

---

For reference, here is what Roslyn's syntax transformation of the script file A) would roughly look like:

```
internal sealed class MyScriptClass
{
     private sealed class <<Initialize>>d__0 : IAsyncStateMachine
     {
       /* .... */
     }

     internal Task<object> <Initialize>()
     {
       /* .... */
     }

     public string myScriptFunction()
     {
       /* ... */
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this method to be called that way? Anyway, if you don't want to use reflection you would need to have some interface your script class would implement (e.g. - IHaveInitialize) and that is visible in the regular code at compile time, but obviously you would need to stick with the C# naming rules...